# Compile with _stdcall under UNIX system

Tags: c, unity-game-engine, plugins, native, stdcall

I'm making a Native Unity Plugin for a linux game, and I have to define C# callbacks, called by my native plugin coded in C.
So the plugin extension is .so since I will compile the game only for linux.

I read on the net that I should annotate these callbacks as `__stdcall` cause there are C# callbacks called from my C lib. Details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx

But it's not possible to compile with `__stdcall` on my functions under UNIX Systems, and I can't compile on windows since it's a library for linux, I call unix functions on this lib.

So what's the point? Is that really necessary to put `__stdcall` on my callbacks ?

EDIT:
Maybe use `__stdecl` is the same? But is this necessary to define it for external callbacks?

Comment: added some informations